# Sublime search specfic keywords as function withn the same file

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

In my project file extension is `.ttcn` and all the function in that file start with `testcase name_of_the_function`.

Is there any Sublime plugin exist that can list all the function that is start with keyword `testcase` followed by test case name?

FYI, most of the common programming languages sublime list all the functions name with shortcut `ctrl'r`. Thanks in advance for any suggestion or recommendation !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Find in Files functionality (**`Find -> Find in Files...`**). In the `Find:` field, make sure the first button (`Regex`) is selected, as well as the last two (`Context` and `Use Buffer`), then enter `^testcase`. Add the directory you'd like to search in the `Where:` field, and make sure the `Replace:` field is empty. Hit the <kbd>Find</kbd> button, and a new tab will open showing all lines that begin with `testcase`.

[image]

Comment: If project folder is added in the side bar then I can see rest other function name start with testcase. In that case is it possible to buffer the search word within the file even project folder is added in the side bar ? Thanks :)

Comment: Is there any github project or plugin exist to fine buffer in the same file only, not entire directory  ?

Comment: @J4cK I'm terribly sorry, but I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking. The `buffer` option just means show the find results in a new tab (a "view" or "buffer" in Sublime-speak) instead of a pop-up window.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I updated the answer. The question I had buffer search both for single file and all the files that are added in the project/ side bar folder in the sublime.